# Can't get codecs for mp4 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I cannot enable mp4s on any sort of video player on a fresh install of ubuntu, though admittedly Ubuntu 10.10, which I have attempted to update via the Ubuntu-Software-Center route. Is there a simple one-liner to install the necessary codecs? Or better still, a non-ffmpeg one-liner to convert to .ogg? 
Right now I get various 'unable to locate package update' messages or 'Broken packages' and such like. Is there any alternative to updating the kernel?

Comment: Download 14.04 and do a fresh install. You'd have to go from 10 to 11 to 12 to 13 to 14 if you want to upgrade.

Comment: Yup sure is looking that way. Thanks. And I think I'll go with Mint. Easy way!

Answer (score 1):

Before installation, run `Try Ubuntu`, Mint or whatever, and check which one suits your video requests. Because you can find out a lot about what suits you particular task at this stage.

You know, there a lot of more or less different or similar Linux distributions and who knows which covers your requests better. So,if you are not a big fan of a deep digging in to manual setting from command line then probably it has a sense to try something in Live CD mode in order to get an intuition for your video issues.

But I believe fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 will deliver you a desired result.